# Levenshtein Distance measuring with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to use Levenshtein Distance with an array
for example i have a div with multiple text

```
<div>one,two,three,longtext,anything</div>
```

and an input

```
<input type="text"> // sometext
```

What im trying to do is measure each one separated by comma with the text in the input. i have tried jquery .split() but it turns up undefined or im doing something wrong there.

Comment: The [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) has a formula. Can you not convert that yourself? Or are you having problems with getting each word from the div into an array?

Comment: ive managed to have this done with one word on the div but im having problems with getting multiple words form the div seperated by comma each one should be compared alone with the value form the input

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Shmiddty/xEyZH/ I'm dumping the distances into the console.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xEyZH/4/, shows results underneath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for everything. You can split a string using the native `s.split(",")`, where `s` is the string you want to split.

For example, provided the function `levenshtein` takes two arguments and returns their levenshtein disttance, you could use the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">one,two,three,longtext,anything</div>
<input id="comparison" type="text">
```

JS:

```
var arr = $('#mydiv').html().split(",");
for(var i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log("distance " + arr[i] + " to " $('#comparison').val() + ":" + levenshtein(arr[i], $('#comparison').val());
}
```

Comment: You stated you tried `jQuery.split`, which is different if it exists. What happens when you try the code above?

Comment: @ErindDollaku "Not working" doesn't give us any hints as to what might be wrong. What do you expect to see? What do you actually see?

Comment: thanks guys that code above works! i could hit the up button but still need to earn some reps